# Set variables from stored procedure from results of another stored procedure

Tags: sql

How can I do something along the following lines?

```
DECLARE @Var1 VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @Var2 VARCHAR(200)

SET @Var1 = value1 from sp_someotherprocedure(@id)
SET @Var2 = value1 from sp_someotherprocedure(@id)
```

Comment: What "results" of a stored procedure do you mean? A stored procedure can have at least three different kinds of "results".

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple example how to from results of stored procedure.
In order to set a variable to the return value from stored procedure you need to use
OUTPUT parameter with stored procedure, which will return the value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourStoredProcedure 
(

    @i    int,
    @result int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET @i = 1
Set @result = @i + 10
return @result
END
```

-- Code to set the output paramter

```
DECLARE @outputparameter AS int
exec @outputparameter =  YourStoredProcedure 10, @outputparameter output
print @outputparameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
EXEC @Var1 = sp_someotherprocedure(@id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures could return many result sets. Therefore, it is not meant to be used with a `SELECT`.
They Could be used in a case where you have [OUTPUT parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You should look into [Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186755.aspx) and then `SELECT` from it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SalesByStore (@storeid varchar(30))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (SELECT t.title, s.qty
    FROM   sales s
    JOIN   titles t ON t.title_id = s.title_id
    WHERE  s.stor_id = @storeid)
```

Then you call it like :

```
SELECT * FROM SalesByStore('6380')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to the party on this one, but just ran into this issue myself. The solution my team and I came up with is to execute the result of the sproc into a temp table, then select top 1 (or whatever meets your criteria) into local variable(s). So using the OP's example might look something like this:

```
DECLARE @Var1 VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @Var2 VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @sprocResult TABLE(val1 INT, val2 INT)

INSERT INTO @sprocResult (val1, val2)
EXEC sp_someotherprocedure @id

SELECT TOP 1 
    @Var1 = val1,
    @Var2 = val2
FROM @sprocResult
```